# H2 database with unitils

Tags: junit, h2, unitils

I used the extension unitils to initialize my database with one of the data sets.
With Mysql, HsqlDB and PostgreSql, I didn't have any problem, but with H2 I foudn problem.
Is what somebody already tested H2 with unitils? If so, thank you to provide the contents of unitils.properties.

below my configuration

```
database.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
database.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test
database.dialect=h2
database.userName=sa
database.password=
database.schemaNames=public

DatabaseModule.Transactional.value.default=disabled

updateDataBaseSchema.enabled=true

dbMaintainer.disableConstraints.enabled=false

dbMaintainer.fromScratch.enabled=true

org.unitils.dbmaintainer.script.ScriptSource.implClassName= org.unitils.dbmaintainer.script.impl.DefaultScriptSource

dbMaintainer.script.locations=./target/test-classes/database/scripts

dataSetStructureGenerator.xsd.dirName=src/test/resources/database/xsd

dbMaintainer.autoCreateExecutedScriptsTable=true

dbMaintainer.script.fileExtensions=sql,ddl

org.unitils.dbmaintainer.clean.DBCleaner.implClassName= org.unitils.dbmaintainer.clean.impl.DefaultDBCleaner
```

and this is the exception I get

```
org.unitils.dbmaintainer.DBMaintainer - Error while initializing DbMaintainer
org.unitils.core.UnitilsException: Missing configuration for org.unitils.core.dbsupport.DbSupport.implClassName
```

I used unitils-dbunit 3.3

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: I modified my question by adding my configuration and the exception that I had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution and I return in order to share it.
The last version of unitils doesn't support H2 database, for that it is necessary to implement the necessary support.
I found the solution in this jira :
https://unitils.atlassian.net/browse/UNI-79